# Why do I hit a hook limitation using AWS Amplify with Github?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, webhooks, aws-amplify

I want to deploy an AWS Amplify app from a Github web project (HTML and CSS only).
I have previously deployed the app, but now I get a hook limitation error when I try to redeploy it

```
There was an issue setting up your repository.
Please try again later.
({
    "message": "Validation Failed",
    "errors": [
        {
            "resource": "Hook",
            "code": "custom",
            "message": "The \"push\" event cannot have more than 20 hooks"
        }
    ],
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-webhook"
})
```

I am using AWS website (UI) to deploy my app.

What are these hooks ?

Comment: How do you deploy the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks limitation comes from github (they are listed in **Settings > Webhooks**)

When deploying an app with Amplify, AWS automatically:

- adds a webhook on the "push" event,
- adds a public SSH key key to the repository
  Afterward a push on the remote repo triggers a redeployment of the application.

In my case I deployed too many times the app. This issue can be encountered when deploying with Terraform.

Special thanks to @Ermiya Eskandary

Answer (score 0):

You have hit the GitHub limit on the number of webhooks you can have, which is 20 as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/about-webhooks).

> You can create up to 20 webhooks for each event on each installation target (specific organization or specific repository).

---

It looks like you have reached this limit based on your error `"The 'push' event cannot have more than 20 hooks"`.

I'm not sure how you're deploying your app but whatever way you are using, it looks like it's creating too many GitHub webhooks.

Take a look to see if there are any options to use pre-existing hooks in your deployment strategy or just simply delete extra hooks from (repository) **Settings** > **Webhooks**.